# shadow in navigationbar when pushing

Tags: ios

please help. When pushing view controller so navigation bar is with shadow.
Is there a way to remove this shadow, please?

I used push/pop with animations YES. 
I tried

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.2 
             animations:^{
                 self.view.frame = CGRectMake(320, 0, 320, 480);
 }];
```

but nothing.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are tone of ways to modify the navigation bar appearance, you can see any examples here:
[www.appcoda.com/customize-navigation-status-bar-ios-7](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-navigation-status-bar-ios-7/)

In your particular case, you can set an empty image as a navigation bar shadow image:

```
[UINavigationBar appearance].shadowImage = [UIImage new];
```